# Syntax error in while loop

Tags: java

I am recieving a syntax error and I can't figure out why. I am in an intro to programming course so my knowledge is very limited. This is a project I have to do and the code I have so far. I just want to test it to see if I am on the right path, but I cant. Any help would be GREATLY appreciate so I can at least see what my next issue is going to be haha.

```
import java.util.*;

public class project2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, I am thinking of a number between 1-100. Take a guess!");
        System.out.print("Please enter your number: ");
        int guess = in.nextInt();
        Random r = new Random(101);
        int counter = 0;
        int totalcount = 6;
        While (counter != totalcount) {      // being told to insert ";" and I have no clue why
            if ( guess < r) {
                System.out.print("You guessed " + guess);
                System.out.println("Too Low");
            } else if ( guess > r) {
                System.out.print("You guessed " + guess);
                System.out.println("Too High");
            } else ( guess = r ) {
                System.out.print("You guessed " + guess);
                System.out.println("YOU'RE PSYCHIC!");
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [The homework tag is deprecated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Answer (score 6):

You have incorrectly capitalised `While`. It should be `while` (all lower-case).

See the documentation for [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

However, there are a number of other issues with your code.

**Firstly**, if you have tested that a number is not greater than or less than it must, by definition be equal. Therefore, you can change

```
else ( guess = r ) {
```

to

```
else
```

This is fortunate for you as `guess = r` will not test for equality. Instead it will assign the value of `r` to `guess`. Also, because `else (condition)` is a syntax error.

**Secondly** You are trying to compare an `int` to a `Random` in this line:

```
if ( guess < r) // r is of type Random, guess is of type Int.
```

What you should actually do is use your `Random` to obtain an int, e.g.:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.nextInt();

if (guess < r) // This is now valid.
```

**Thirdly** You have seeded your random number generator with 101. This means that it will always return the same sequence of numbers. This may be what you want but, if it is not, you can just use the paramaterless constructor to seed it with the current time in milliseconds

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
else ( guess = r ) {
```

Change condition into comment.

```
else { // ( guess == r )
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not capitalize the word "while". Case is very important in Java.

Answer (score 1):

bunch of problems. See fix below.

1. Do not capitalize 'While'
2. if you do an else and want to check another condition, do an 'else if (...)'
3. you can't compare an int to a variable of type 'Random'. Instead save off Random.nextInt() and compare that
4. When comparing, make sure if you want 'is equal to' you use '==' not '='. The latter is the assignment operator, while '==' is the comparison operator.

   ```
    import java.util.Random;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class project2 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Welcome, I am thinking of a number between 1-100. Take a guess!");

       System.out.print("Please enter your number: ");

       int guess = in.nextInt();

       Random r = new Random(101);
       int actual = r.nextInt();

       int counter = 0;

       int totalcount = 6;

       while (counter != totalcount) { // being told to insert ";" and I have no clue why

           if (guess < actual) {

               System.out.print("You guessed " + guess);

               System.out.println("Too Low");
           }

           else if (guess > actual) {

               System.out.print("You guessed " + guess);

               System.out.println("Too High");
           }

           else if (guess == actual) {

               System.out.print("You guessed " + guess);

               System.out.println("YOU'RE PSYCHIC!");

           }

           counter++;
       }

   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

`guess = r` is an assignment rather than a comparison.  In this case the comparison is unnecessary as its the default case, but for future reference, `guess == r` is the correct way to do a comparison (assuming that guess is an int or other primitive)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Random r = new Random(101);
```

to

```
Random random = new Random();
int r = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

You need an `int` to compare to the guess. You're using a `Random` which is a random number generator.  The `Random` method `nextInt(int i)` returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and `i` exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Found three things

1) While incorrectly capitalized

2) r is the wrong type for comparison with integer, it's an instance of "Random"

3) you mean == and not =

I found all these errors by loading the program into Eclipse.  I suggest you get a similar editor to help with these problems!

Hope this helps